# Restoring deleted MySQL database from log file

Tags: mysql

Last Night I accidently deleted a production MySql database on a digital ocean droplet. I immediately shut down apache and MySql. I have the following ib* files:

- ib_buffer_pool
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1
- ibdata1
- ibtmp1

Is there anyway I can restore my database from these files? Does anyone have a program or know of one that can rebuild this? If not a program, a way to role back the latest changes to the server?

I have no back-up.

Comment: What filesystem are you using, and have you written to it since deleting this database?

Comment: I have seen data stored in the ib_logfile1 file even after dropping tables. I am not sure if you can recover info from that file or not, maybe Percona has a tool that could help you.

Comment: You can also try making an image of your partition before making any changes to ensure you don't overwrite anything. If you have multiple disks, use `dd bs=4M if=/dev/partition of=partition.backup` if you don't, you can use the command remotely over ssh.

Comment: True, there may be some pieces of data in the binary log if that was enabled, but it would only be a small subset of the database in almost every case

Comment: @Jay now you know,  that you need always to have a backup :)

Answer (score 4):

No, sorry. Those files are from the innodb storage engine, and are journals, logs, etc. While journaling does ensure data consistency, it only uses metadata to do so - so if you have no data to go with it, you're not recovering anything.

But that's maybe not as much of an issue as it might seem. Most filesystems are relatively easy to recover data from *as long as you do not write to it in any way*. A write may overwrite your old deleted data. After a deletion, a file is simply taken out of the "filesystem index", leaving the actual data behind (which can be overwritten with new data if you use the filesystem).

`testdisk` is an excellent utility for restoring (un-deleting) files. There are several others that you may use, many of which are filesystem specific. They should be run on an unmounted block device. So if you want to recover this data, you should stop using this volume immediately and open it with `testdisk` or similar. You should also make an image of the underlying block device and work from that, rather than operating on your original. `dd` is a great utility for doing that.

Maybe you have volume snapshots of some kind? That would allow you to roll back this change, potentially. You could also use that to snapshot your volume in its current state before attempting a recovery, circumventing the need for copying the entire block device.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to note the "no" answer is logically false. Because if you don't know a solution that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Now, the main question what was `innodb_file_per_table`, ON or OFF. The default in recent versions is ON, so most likely the data was deleted together with respective `*.ibd` files. Successful recovery greatly depends on how soon you stopped writes to MySQL partition. Take the partition image ASAP and work with the image. I don't recommend undeleting *.ibd files, this method proved to yield less recovered data. I suspect the main reason if that a file undelete tool must reconstruct a file and may sacrifice chunks with data. Your goal however is get the records back, so I recommend to look for InnoDB pages instead. `stream_parser` from [Undrop for InnoDB](https://github.com/twindb/undrop-for-innodb) (I'm the author) does it. See step-by-step instructions in my blog post https://twindb.com/recover-after-drop-table-innodb_file_per_table-on/

If innodb_file_per_table was OFF the job is easier - all data is in ibdata1, there is a less chance to overwrite the data if you stopped MySQL immediately.
Follow this post for this case - https://twindb.com/recover-innodb-table-after-drop-table-innodb/.

In both cases you will need to recover the schema. You can take it from old backups (if any), installation scripts - anything similar. If you have nothing the last resort is to recover the schema from InnoDB dictionary. It resides in ibdata1 - the post on how to do that https://twindb.com/recover-table-structure-from-innodb-dictionary/. Please note - the structure must be 100% accurate.

Overall I must admit chances are slim, but if you act fast and with some deal of luck you can recover some if not all data.

So, good luck.